# Find number of ones to get a number using + and *

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic, integer, expression-building

## Introduction

Your goal is to find the least number of ones you need to add or multiply together to get the input value, this is [A005245](//oeis.org/A005245).

### Input

One positive integer ***N***.

### Output

The smallest number of ones that must be added/multiplied to get ***N***.

#### Sample Input

> 7

#### Sample Output

> 6

#### Explanation

> (`1` + `1` + `1`) * (`1` + `1`) + `1` = 7
>
> Because this requires `6` ones, the output is `6`

#### Test cases

```
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 5  5
10  7
20  9
50 12
```

As this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, lowest number of bytes wins.

Comment: [OEIS A005245](https://oeis.org/A005245)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! As a first challenge this is OK, but next time please use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before posting challenges so you can get feedback!

Comment: I'd suggest modifying this to explicitly state that you're looking for the *minimum* number of ones required. Otherwise, simply outputting the original number and claiming that it's the number of ones you need to add together would be a valid solution.

Comment: To clarify, you meant "using + and * ". Exponentiation would allow fewer, e.g. 9 = (1 + 1 + 1) ^ (1 + 1) ; uses 5 ones, not 6.

Comment: Are there examples where `f(x) != x.primeFactorisation().sum()` except 1?

Comment: @jrtapsell:  yes.  The given example of $f(7)=6$ is one.  For any (large enough) prime $p$ you can factor $p-1$ and add one.  You may be able to do better yet.

Comment: @Ross Fun fact (taken from the oeis page): the smallest prime number p such that f(p) doesn't equal f(p-1)+1 is p=353942783

Comment: @jrtapsell: Yes, many primes or pseudoprimes, esp. near multiples of a large power of 2 or 3 might be more compactly written as that power + a small offset. Examples: a) 13 = 2*2*3+1 (requires 8) and b) 129 = 2*2*2*2*2*2*2 + 1 (requires 15, not 129). Intuitively, the "optimal" factorization will generally involve powers of 2 and 3 such that we are approximating e^x.

Comment: Bonus points if solutions work up to known counterexamples n = 353942783 and n = 516743639 ?

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>74</s> 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:min([n]+[f(j)+min(n%j*n+f(n/j),f(n-j))for j in range(2,n)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/BasMwEETP1lcMFBNtrFBHpRdDesxPhBxcJLUS9SqoCqQt/XZ3FXoaZnZ3Hnv5qu@Z7bqGw8e8vLoZPC2R9YnPwynoRENz3KctD0HzYyIjsktEIRckREaZ@c1ra5jOtDofUP1n1dsbTaprS9yWbmK6S4lcsentFbsXiGzQQ7OBVBIpdT/cG1iDJ4Nng/0o6QMWv@T4PdeYWTVAaDdHHBAMnMjPb2PFICjOteHcBCcvyOwo1aorvl4L37N/jB2FMNL6Bw)

#### Alternate version, 59 bytes (unverified)

```python
f=lambda n:min([n]+[f(j)+f(n/j)+f(n%j)for j in range(2,n)])
```

This works at least up to **n = 1,000,000**, but I have yet to prove that it works for all positive **n**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BbsIwEETP8VeMhCJsMCK46iUSPfITiEOQ7dYRWSPXkQJVvz2sgdNod2fm7fWWfyKZefb7SzecbQdqh0DySKf10cterb2k7UvqXvmY0CMQUkffThpN6qRm6zyy@81yNalWVMVExTTxUF1ToIxlbUZsvsCyRA1JGtyolBDP4E7DaHxofGrsGt4uMLghhnuXQyRRAL5kDtjDa1iWv//CCp5RFHPB2RaW/@bbgatFlVweEz13b4xpmNCo@QE)

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something simple, but it's not obvious to be that this tries every viable expression tree. In particular, we have outer layer `n=a*j+b` with `b<j`, but might we need `b>=j`?

Comment: Hm, it would only fail if both `b>=j` and `b>=a`. But you're right, it's not obvious that this won't happen.

Comment: Interesting that there's no counterexamples up to 1,000,000, I wonder if it actually just always works. My best thought for a counterexample would be something of form `a*b+c*d` with `a,b,c,d` all summation expressions and are very efficient.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

Thanks Dennis for saving 2 bytes!

```
ÆḌḊ,Ṗß€€+U$FṂo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28MdPQ93dOk83Dnt8PxHTWuASDtUxe3hzqb8////GxoAAA)

---

### Logic explanation

Given a number **n**:

- If it's `1`, the answer is `1`. Otherwise:

The representation is either `a + b` or `a × b`, where `a` and `b` are expressions.

Consider all possible values of `a` and `b`:

- If the representation is `a + b`, then `a` and `b` are in range `[1 .. n-1]`.
- If the representation is `a × b`, `a` and `b` are proper divisors of `n` larger than `1`.

In both cases, the list `[[<proper divisors of n larger than 1>], [1, 2, ..., n-1]]` is computed (`ÆḌḊ,Ṗ`), map the current link over each number `ß€€`, add the correct pairs together (`+U$`) and get the minimum value (`FṂo`).

### Code explanation

```
ÆḌḊ,Ṗß€€+U$FṂo   Main link. Assume n = 10.
ÆḌ       Proper divisors. [1,2,5]
  Ḋ      Ḋequeue, remove the first element. [2,5]
   ,Ṗ    Pair with Ṗop. Auto convert n = 10 to range 
         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and remove the last element
         10, get [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].

ß€€      Apply this link over each element.
   +U$   Add with the Upend of itself.

FṂ       Flatten and get the Ṃinimum element.
  o      Logical or with n.
         If the list is empty, minimum returns 0 (falsy), so logical or
         convert it to n.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 66 bytes

A port of [Dennis's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154240/9288):

```
f(n)=vecmin(concat(n,[f(j)+min(n%j*j+f(n\j),f(n-j))|j<-[2..n-1]]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3BCoMwEER/ZSkUdjUrjefaH4keJJiSha4hSE/@e1wv82B4zJS1Zv6W1hIqTf8t/rJi3DWuB6oLCYX6u9KndNKbNAs5AwvRKW8O4zAo@2UhammvqDCBd@BfDkrNaiPwAP5Y3AcmXQ)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 72 bytes

Longer, but more efficient:

```
f(n)=if(n<6,n,vecmin([if(d>1,f(d)+f(n/d),1+f(n-1))|d<-divisors(n),d<n]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xDsJACAbg3acgTkfk4jHU6doXMQ5GrGGQXq5NJ9/9pDFRlz/wEaBcq8ZHaW0Mhr165hMZrffbUy2cHWRg8sSDz46CxFsRGfElOYquOk919mWSbBfENk41GPTABJwISlVbHPYQB4/tDeLuo136cZe@zOnPvfGjbw)

Comment: Dennis improved his method and using that can save you 11 bytes: `f(n)=vecmin(concat(n,[f(j)+f(n\j)+f(n%j)|j<-[2..n-1]]))`.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>108</s> 96 bytes

```
f=n=>n<6?n:Math.min(...[...Array(n-2)].map((_,i)=>Math.min(f(++i)+f(n-i),n%++i/0||f(i)+f(n/i))))
```

Very inefficient; `Array(n>>1)` speeds it up slightly at a cost of a byte. Explanation: `n%++i` is non-zero if `i` is not a factor, so `n%++i/0` is `Infinity` (and therefore truthy, and also definitely not minimal) if `i` is not a factor, but `NaN` (and therefore falsy) if `i` is a factor. Edit: Saved 12 bytes with inspiration from @edc65.

Comment: I tried running this in the background to see whether it was in fact capable of calculating `f(50)` but unfortunately Windows Update rebooted my PC before it could finish.

Comment: Did you try a single walk on the a array?

Comment: @edc65 Sorry, but I'm unclear as to what you're suggesting and why.

Comment: I see 2 maps, each one scanning the `a` array. Can't you merge the evaluations in the 2 lambdas and take the min?

Comment: @edc65 Ah yes, for some reason I thought nesting the min wouldn't be cheaper but I get to replace `(i+=2)` with another `++i` so I'm saving 12 bytes in total, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 213 bytes

**Edit:** I've been [severely beaten](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154244/61563).

```
f(n)={d;n<6&return(n);if(n<=#a,a[n]&return(a[n]),a=vector(n));for(i=1,n-1,a[i]||a[i]=f(i));a[n]=min(vecmin(vector(n\2,k,a[k]+a[n-k])),if(isprime(n),n,vecmin(vector((-1+#d=divisors(n))\2,i,a[d[i+1]]+a[d[#d-i]]))))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BDoIwDIYfhsSsoTtMoxfYk@AOi2OmIRQykIv47LMzevCyLn@//@vsE@n7nHNUDPYZGm4vh9Svj8QSNCRxayuPvmP3y8sf0Nutv61TEgyaKJOsQdZGUHL7Xl4bFcmy8HYkVlL4jk/vesRB6MHVQujBAaDco2VONPaiRcb/htKmroINtNEypaVcFgeJI3RUG1dEoauCJicygFcWFa8qqvMJIL8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 181 bytes

```python
def F(N,n,s="",r=""):
 try:
	if n<1:return(eval(s)==N)*0**(`11`in s or"**"in s)*s
	for c in"()+*1":r=F(N,~-n,s+c)or r
 except:r
 return r
f=lambda N,n=1:F(N,n).count(`1`)or f(N,-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY69DsIwDIRn@hRWpjgERPhZIrIy9hlaSiIqgVu5AcHCqxcHFut0Z/u78Z2vA23n@RITnHRtyU5BKcsy0FeQ@e2rRZ@Ajs5zzA8mHZ/tTU8YQo1mY4xunGt6ggkGVsaoItFM1SINDB30pDQujVOeQwF8VoJYdighVxBfXRyzF/V/Ll4Kt/Z@vrQgZYLzv1K47oYHZUE15TCJt/oQzgVRCwK0s7C1sLOwt3BADyP3lMsizl8)

Comment: @pizzapants184 The main function `f` must not be anonymous, as it calls itself recursively.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 59 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Martin Ender. Using CP-1252 encoding, where `±` is one byte.

```
±1=1;±n_:=Min[1+±(n-1),±#+±(n/#)&/@Divisors[n][[2;;-2]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78///QRkNbQ@tDG/PirWx9M/OiDbUPbdTI0zXU1Dm0URnM1lfWVNN3cMksyyzOLyqOzouNjjayttY1io2N/e@SHx1QlJlXEp2no6CkoGunoKSjADQrVkehGihiCEQGtbHWXBA1pgbIikwN4BKGBigyQG6s9X8A)

Comment: Using `±` instead of `f` saves 3 bytes assuming the source is encoded in CP 1252: https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78///QRkNbQ@tDG/PirWx9M/OiDbUPbdTI0zXU1Dm0URnM1lfWVNN3cMksyyzOLyqOzouNjjayttY1io2N/e@SHx1QlJlXEp2no6CkoGunoKSjADQrVkehGihiCEQGtbHWXBA1pgbIikwN4BKGBigyQG6s9X8A

Comment: Does not work correctly for input 353942783.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), -p 78 bytes

79 bytes in old style counting (`+1` for `-p`)

The fact that perl must use an extra `$` for all scalar access really hurts the length of golfs that do a lot of arithmetic...

This method is mostly like the others already posted (try multiplication and addition to build a target number, take the cheapest). It however doesn't repeatedly recurse down so it can be used for relatively large inputs.

It also doesn't try to minimize the cost of building a number by addition or multip[lication because perl 5 has no builtin `min` and numeric sort is looooooong (as seen from the sort still in the code). Instead I just assume if a number is a factor of the target that I will use multiplication. That is safe since if e.g. `3` is a factor of `12` (so it sums the cost of `3` and `12/3`) later in the loop it will consider `9=12-3` which will not be a factor, so `9+3` with the same cost as `3+9` will get tried anyways. However that may fail for targets `<= 4` (it only does for `1` and `2`). Adding `$_` to the list to minimize fixes that. Which is unfortunate since I don't actually need that for the base cases because I already initialize `@;` with the proper starting values so it costs 3 bytes.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
($_)=sort{$a-$b}$_,map{$;[$_]+$;[$'%$_?$'-$_:$'/$_]}//..$_ for@;=0..$_;$_=pop@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCsIwEEbhq3TxSxSbZLroxhDsPUSGChUEdYakrkqv7mhX7@PpVJ69ferU9KGjQMn24EOuUuYFo8dtBbevURekC/h63OJ24DOcB5/g4v@uMYYAbu5ShpRpcwJnFR3MOiL6is4PeVfz@gM)