# Minimum 1's to get 1-expression for n

Tags: code-golf, number

#### Background

Challenge is inspired by [this question](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73925/the-1-expression).

The 1-expression is a formula that in which you add and multiply the number 1 any number of times. Parenthesis is allowed, but concatenating 1's (e.g. 11) is not allowed.

Here is an example to get the 1-expression for \$19\$:

```
(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1+1+1)+1+1+1 = 19
```

Total number of \$1\$'s is \$11\$ but there is shorter than this:

```
(1+1)*(1+1+1)*(1+1+1)+1 = 19
```

Total number of \$1\$'s is \$9\$.

#### Program

Given a positive integer `n` output the minimum 1's to get the 1-expression for `n`.

**Notes:**

- For reference, the sequence is [A005245](//oeis.org/A005245).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in each language wins!

#### Test cases

```
Input -> Output | 1-Expression
1 -> 1 | 1
6 -> 5 | (1+1+1)*(1+1)
22 -> 10 | (1+1)*((1+1+1+1+1)*(1+1)+1)
77 -> 14 | (1+1)*(1+1)*((1+1+1)*(1+1+1)*(1+1)+1)+1
214 -> 18 | ((((1+1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
2018 -> 23 | (((1+1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1+1)*(1+1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
```

Comment: First time posting a challenge. [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17003)

Comment: Very well-written first challenge. Unfortunately, I believe it's an exact duplicate of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154236/42545) from earlier this year (which happens to be that user's first challenge too). So sorry this wasn't caught in the Sandbox...

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>76</s> 71 bytes

```
If[#<2,1,Min[#+Reverse@#&/@{#0/@Range[#-1],#0/@Most@Rest@Divisors@#}]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8zLVrZxkjHUMc3My9aWTsotSy1qDjVQVlN36Fa2UDfISgxLz01WlnXMFYHxPXNLy5xCEoFEi6ZZZnF@UXFDsq1sbFq//UdFCBKDQ1iY/8DAA)

The recursive approach: define `f[n]` to be the minimum of `f[k]+f[n-k]`over all `k` less than `n`, and `f[d] + f[n/d]`over all divisors of `n` (other than `1` and `n` itself).